# Работа со временем в JS

Tags: javascript, время

Значит s.cal[id].time выводит время из определенного элемента (не текущее) в формате Ч:М (12:00), как состряпать условие, которое будет брать время и плюсовать к нему например 50 минут и сравнивать с текущим, если истина выполняем определенный код?
Что-то вроде этого...

```js
if (s.cal[id].time + 50 min >= time) {
//что-то делаем
};
```

Comment: [How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

Comment: какой результат должен быть, если на выходе больше 24 часов получается? например, если к 23:50 добавлять 50 минут?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Т.к. нужно просто сравнить... `чч * 60 + мм`

```js
let time = "23:24"; // s.cal[id].time;

let d = new Date();

let prev = calc_minutes(...time.split(":"));
let curr = calc_minutes(d.getHours(), d.getMinutes());

console.log( prev, curr, prev + 50 > curr );

function calc_minutes(hh, mm) {
  return hh * 60 + Number(mm);
}
```

При необходимости `prev + 50 > curr` заменить на `(prev + 50) % (24 * 60) > curr`, чтобы 24:30 считался как 00:30

Comment: Благодарю, это то что надо, только вот почему-то пришлось в prev + 50 > curr знак < развернуть, но работает как надо))

Comment: @Влад О_о значит не работает как надо... Учитывали, что new Date() дает время в зависимости от часового пояса пользователя?

Comment: Часовой пояс не учитывал)

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а можно в код еще добавить проверку даты? А то на элементы которые идут на будущую дату но меньшее время подпадают по действие кода...

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/date — Есть разные варианты собрать дату из строки. Зависит от исходного формата, в котором указывается дата в текстовом виде.

Comment: А не подскажете что прописать, чтоб просто была проверка соответствия текущей даты и даты элемента? Тогда действие кода не будет распространяться на прошлые и будущие дни, только на текущий, формат стандартный день.месяц.год, через точку)

Comment: @Влад `let [day, month, year] = "11.02.2021".split(".").map(Number); let d = new Date(); if ( d.getFullYear() == year && ( d.getMonth() == month - 1 ) && d.getDate() == day ) { /* дни одинаковые */ }` можно конечно оформить чуть красивше, или сделать функцию, которая выполнит это всё внутри.

Answer (score 4):

Если не используете библиотеки, то вот так должно работать. Но, если вам часто надо работать с датой\временем, то лучше использовать `momentjs`.

```js
// s.cal[id].time + 50 min >= time


function parseTimeHHMM(stringTime) {
  return time.split(":").map(Number);
}

function setTime(date, hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0, ms = 0) {
  date.setHours(hours, minutes, seconds, ms);
}

function addMinutes(date, minutes = 0) {
  date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + minutes);
}

const time = "12:00";
// парсим строку в часы и минуты (еще хорошо бы знать формат AM\PM или 24 часовой)
const [hours, minutes] = parseTimeHHMM(time);

const timeDate = new Date();
//устанавливаем время для объекта даты
setTime(timeDate, hours, minutes);
// создаем новую дату
const in50MinutesDate = new Date(timeDate);
//добавляем 50 минут
addMinutes(in50MinutesDate, 50);
const currentDate = new Date();

console.log(currentDate, timeDate, in50MinutesDate);

//сравниваем даты
if (in50MinutesDate >= currentDate) {
  console.log('yes');
} else {
  console.log('no');
}
```

Comment: [`setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) может принимать 4 параметра, поэтому вместо твоей функции `setTime` можно использовать нативную

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, не знал!

Answer (score 2):

Если писать с костылями, то в том формате, в котором задан вопрос, будет работать следующее:

```js
var hours = (s.cal[id].time).split(":")[0];
var minutes = (s.cal[id].time).split(":")[1];
var addedMinutes = 50;
var time = "12:30"; //время, с которым сравниваем
var hoursCompare = time.split(":")[0];
var minutesCompare = time.split(":")[1];
hours = parseInt(hours, 10) + Math.floor((minutes + addedMinutes)/60);
minutes = parseInt(minutes, 10) + ((minutes + addedMinutes)%60);

if (hours >= hoursCompare && minutes >= minutesCompare) {
  //что-то делаем
};
```

P.s. давно это делал, могут быть ошибки в синтаксисе, но общая суть такая

Comment: Ваше решение не работает на границе дня, к сожалению.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, да. мой косяк, в вопросе про это не было, поэтому забыл